# Two Same Maven Dependencies (spring boot starters) with "provided" and "compile" scopes

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-dependency, spring-boot-starter, spring-autoconfiguration

I have two maven projects. In first project I import two same dependencies that spring boot starters.
For example:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Second dependency has compile scope (by default).
In second project I import first project as dependency.
When I run second project (spring boot application) and use some classes from this dependency than autoconfiguration works.
But When I don't use some classes than autoconfiguration doesn't work.
Why it works this way?
I expect autoconfiguration will work always in this cases. It maybe feature

Comment: It does not make sense to declare a dependency more than once. A dependency can have only one scope.

Comment: That should produce a WARNING during building ....